# HIVE Partition table move to another DB

Tags: hadoop, hive

- I have created two database DB1 and DB2 from HIVE terminal.
- ran "use DB1" and has created ORC formatted table T1 having partition as Year, month and date and loaded it with  some records.
- ran "use DB2", and there I create ORC formatted Table T2 suing DDL script and it is  having same structure as DB1.T1.
- I inserted   few records in DB2.T2 so that in HDFS- Hive warehouse some directory structure is created for the partition.
- I ran Hadoop fs -cp /apps/hive/warehouse/DB1.db/T1/* /apps/hive/warehouse/DB2.db/T2
- it copied the files and build remaining directory structure in /apps/hi../DB2.T2.

Problem is select count from DB2.T2 is not returning latest records which are copied from DB1.T1.

Can some one explain reason behind it please?
It works for the normal Text formatted table.

Thanks,

Abhi

Comment: Can you show command by command exactly what you have run?

Comment: 1. Create database DB1;
2. use DB1;
3. 
CREATE  TABLE `e1`(
  `name` string,
PARTITIONED BY (
  `year` int,
  `month` int,
  `day` int,
  `id` int)
stored as orc;



4. 
insert into table e1 partition(year,month,day,site_id)
SELECT 
name,
year,
month,
day,
id
from master;

5. Create database DB2;
6. use DB2;
7. 
CREATE  TABLE `e_arc`(
  `name` string,
  PARTITIONED BY (
  `year` int,
  `month` int,
  `day` int,
  `id` int)
stored as orc;
8. haddop fs -cp /apps/hive/warehouse/db1.db/e1/* /apps/hive/warehouse/db2.db/e_arc/
9. select * from e_arc  returns null.Normal table works with these steps.

Answer (score 0):

So as to get the statistics like count of records faster, HIVE now gets that from metadata which is updated during the insert process(only exception is metadata does not have count populated). In case you are adding partitions or files to hive table manually make sure you run ANALYZE command as shown below.

```
analyze table t [partition p] compute statistics for [columns c,...];
```

Also in case of manual addition of partition outside not via hive command, run the repair table command

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;
or 
ALTER TABLE table_name RECOVER PARTITIONS;
```